# Binary Numbers - Difference between 15 and -1

Tags: binary, twos-complement

I was learning binary numbers and 2's complement.

Lets say I have the binary number 1111. This is 15, but is also -1 (got from 2's complement method).

Can you explain how do i tell if it is 15 or -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the data type you use. Most programming languages offer signed and unsigned types.

A series of bits means nothing without a data type. E.g. an unsigned Int16 would contain only positive numbers up to 16 bits, while a signed Int16 would also contain negative numbers (but of course, less positive ones).

Comment: He's specifically asking about 2's complement, so.. signed :)

Comment: He asked how to distinguish -1 from 15. So 1111 maybe 15 (unsigned) or -1 (signed).

Comment: Oh ok, my bad, I should have read the question more carefully... Removing my misleading answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of definition. If I write 10, you could read ten (decimal) or two (binary) or a whole bunch of other numbers, depending on the number system. If you don't know which system I use, there's no way you  can tell what I mean. In your case, 15 is an answer in a unsigned binary system, -1 is an answer in a 2's compliment binary system.

Answer (score 0):

If the register is 4-bit 2's complement, then the maximum range of values possible to be achieved is -8 to 7, so 15 is out of the question. For 15 to be represented, an unsigned register has to be used.